# What part of speech is "born"?

Tags: passive-voice, past-participles

> I was born in 1980.

What part of speech is "born"? verb? past participle?

It can be a past participle as in " I was seen ."

It can be verb as in " It was pulled by a car ."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both *seen* and *pulled* in your examples are past participles employed in passive constructions.

Note that it is meaningless to ask if a form is a 'participle **or** a verb'. A participle is a verb inflection which may act as a verb or as another part of speech *or* as both simultaneously. The past participle, for instance, may act either as a component of a passive or perfect construction or as an adjective or as both a passive component *and* an adjective:

> We have seen that man.
>   That man has been seen by us.
>   That is the man seen by us.

*Born* is tricky. In origin it is the past participle of the verb *bear* meaning *carry*. As far back as we can see, women and female animals have been said to *bear* their young while pregnant and to *have borne* their young when the pregnancy ended in a live offspring. *BE born* was originally the passive version of the same verb.

Eventually, however, the passive sense bleached out of the passive form. When we speak today of a child *being born*, there is no longer a sense that this was an ***action*** performed upon the child by the mother; it is, rather, an ***event***.  We no longer say that *John Smith was born on April 1, 1950 **by** Mary Jones Smith*; we say at most that *John Smith was born on April 1, 1950 **to** Mary Jones Smith*. This 'depassivized' sense is hinted at in spelling: today we spell the past participle of *bear* as ‹borne›, but the corresponding term in the birth idiom is ‹born›, without the ‹e›.

Somewhere over on ELU John Lawler has suggested that *BE born* is a unique English *deponent* verb—a verb which is passive in form but active in sense. That's a very attractive suggestion if you're familiar with the notion of deponent verbs; but I think it's more helpful to think of *BE born* as a unique idiom which cannot usefully be decomposed beyond what is needed to allow for inflecting *BE*.

Comment: While I understand the difference between "born to" and "born by" in the context even without ELL, I do not really understand the explanation regarding the action and the event. I mean, I understand the words, but I cannot really agree with them, in this short fragment of text. _Is there some reference available on the subject, please?_

Answer (score 1):

It is the past-participle of *bear*.   The mother bears the child. The child is born.  It is synonymous with "carried", past-participle of "carry". The mother carries the baby in her womb.

Comment: W e l l . . . There's at least a touch of etymological fallacy there. We distinguish the PaPpl of *bear* orthographically: it's *borne*. And I think that reflects a semantic reality: although the mother *bears* the child all the way to birth, the child is not *born* until the birth is perfected.

Comment: Do you really see this as etymological *fallacy*? The mother is bearing the child (in her womb) = the mother is carrying the child (in her womb). The child has been born = the mother has carried the child to term and has "given birth" to the child.

Comment: I meant merely that the etymological connection with *bear* has been largely bleached out of the idiom. I think it's important to tell learners that *BE born* is no longer deployed as a passive construction; we do not say *She was born in 1912 by Enid Milhouse* or *By whom was she born?*

Comment: @StoneyB: True, dat. We find only the vestiges "He was born to poor parents" or  "he was born of a noble family" or "a Savior is born to us" or "he was born of a woman".

Answer (score 1):

The base forms of to bear are bear/bore/borne. Beside borne there is a second form "born" used only in sentences like  "I was born in 2001".