# Which prepositions collocate with "to be born"?

Tags: prepositions

> A baby girl was born **to** Mr Arthur Keller and Kate Keller.

Why does it use 'to' instead of 'by'?

Please tell me differences.

Note: An [answer to a related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/60483/3281) does touch on this some. I would like more information about "to" vs. "by" here.

Comment: This question is now closed as duplicate, because it already has an answer here: [What part of speech is “born”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/60483/3281). Are you the same user? If so, have you read the answer linked to in that question? (The part from "Born is tricky" should answer your question, in my humble opinion.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. - Help me understand this, please. One question asks: _In the sentence, "I was born in 1980," what part of speech is ‘born’?_ This one asks: _In the sentence, "A baby girl was born to Mr Arthur Keller and Kate Keller," why does it use ‘to’ instead of ‘by’?_ **How is that a duplicate question???** Aside from the word _born_, I can't even see how they are related. If anything, it seems like maybe Stoney's answer could have inspired this question.

Comment: @J.R. It's true that the two questions ask two different things, but StoneyB's answer should answer this OP's question (I will expand on that in another comment). IMHO, StoneyB's didn't inspire this question, or else the OP could've said so. I didn't choose to vote to close right away but asked the OP specifically if they read StoneyB's answer, so we could proceed appropriately, but no feedback so far.

Comment: (cont.) Still, IMHO, my guess was that either the OP never read StoneyB's answer or the OP had read StoneyB's answer but didn't understand, which would cast this question as yet another question ("How can I understand this text?") -- As it stands, I believe that by answering the other question, StoneyB's explained quite clearly the difference between *born to* and *born by*. We could answer this question by copying parts of text in StoneyB's answer: ...

Comment: (cont.): "Which prepositions collocate with 'to be born'?" "to" "Why does it use 'to' instead of 'by'?" "When we speak today of a child being born, there is no longer a sense that this was an action performed upon the child by the mother; it is, rather, an event. (We no longer say that John Smith was born on April 1, 1950 by Mary Jones Smith; we say at most that John Smith was born on April 1, 1950 to Mary Jones Smith. )"

Comment: To recap, I believe that it's up to us and largely up to the OP to tell us and how we all choose to help the OP out of their confusion. We could choose to act "as is". We could choose to wait for the OP's feedback and then proceed. We may be able to choose to come up with some other alternative. Which choice we'd chosen, or will choose, I'd humbly respect opinions of other ELL fellows, and of the community as a whole.

Comment: @Damk - Thanks for taking the time to answer. I agree with your recap, and that this question might have avoided closure had it referenced the other as part of its "prior research". However, this is a new user (and my mod tools tell me it's NOT the person who asked that other question), As such, I don't think this O.P. got a very fitting welcome into our community.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the common prepositions we use with ***born***, as listed in a definition given by the Macmillan Dictionary:

> **[born](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/born)**
>   [adjective]
>
> 1. [never before noun] when a baby is born, it comes out of its mother’s body and starts its life. The time when you are born is your birth, and a mother gives birth to a baby
>      *Her grandfather died before she was born.*
>      **born in:** *I was born in Tokyo.*
>      **born on:** *The twins were born on August 29, 1962.*
>      **born into:** *Meg was born into a large family.*
>      **born to:** *More children are now born to older women.*

In short, we use *born in* a place, *born on* a date, *born into* a family, *born to* a mother (or parents, as in your example).

According to an [answer to a related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/60483/3281), this part gives us a good reason why we don't use ***born by*** anymore:

> When we speak today of a child *being born*, there is no longer a sense that this was an ***action*** performed upon the child by the mother; it is, rather, an **event**. We no longer say that *John Smith was born on April 1, 1950 **by** Mary Jones Smith*; we say at most that *John Smith was born on April 1, 1950 **to** Mary Jones Smith*.